# How to tweak Python Sphinx so that I can have a fine site search result?

Tags: python, scipy, python-sphinx

I really like Python-Sphinx documentation tool but one thing annoys me is that I can barely get proper search result from the sphinx search box:

[image]

So I am wondering is there any trick so that I can have a better search performance from Sphinx search box? Also, is there any tool that allow me to replace Sphinx search box with a custom google search?

Thanks!

Edit: I just found out [Scipy](http://scipy.org/#) search box auto link to google. I am wondering if anyone knows how they achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

The Sphinx search function is currently not very powerful/configurable.

To solve your problem, you can either

1. implement your own Sphinx search or
2. adjust your Sphinx template to support a custom Google search.

For 1), you might want to look into the **non-stable** Sphinx extension [sphinxcontrib-lunrsearch 0.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-lunrsearch).

For 2), read the [Sphinx templating documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/templating.html).

There are some open issues in the [Sphinx project on GitHub](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/labels/html%20search) that might go into the direction of what you want, so you could try to contribute back to the project and get the support of the Sphinx community.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll take a look at the links you suggested :D

Answer (score 1):

The integration of the Google Searchbox is described in the Sphinx FAQ section at and you need to apply for a Google account. It worked for me as expected. Maybe you may need to tweak CSS Z-Index to avoid overlay of search results by contents depending on your theme.

from: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/faq.html?highlight=google%20search

## Google Search

To replace Sphinx’s built-in search function with Google Search, proceed as follows:

1. Go to https://cse.google.com/cse/all to create the Google Search code snippet.
2. Copy the code snippet and paste it into
   `_templates/searchbox.html` in your Sphinx project:

   ```
   <div>
      <h3>{{ _('Quick search') }}</h3>
      <script>
         (function() {
            var cx = '......';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
         })();
      </script>
     <gcse:search></gcse:search>
   </div>
   ```
3. Add `searchbox.html` to the `html_sidebars` configuration value.